# Does a gain in one brokerage account and a loss in another brokerage balance each other out for tax purposes?

Tags: taxes, stocks, income-tax, tax-deduction, losses

I have different investments in two different brokerage accounts A and B.

Investments in A are up 500 and in B are down 500. If I were to sell both of these in the same year (without any other losses / gains in the year) would I need to pay any taxes on the 500$ gain at all (due to the 500 balancing it out)?

The 500$ are currently subject to capital gains tax. Will this be deducted before the loss is taken into consideration?

Comment: What country are you asking about? Tax rules vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the situation is as simple as that, the gain and the loss would offset and there would be no taxation or deductions.  It's a break even.

The only possible complication would be if there was a purchase of substantially identical securities to B withing 30 days (before and after) realizing the loss, creating a carry forward wash sale violation on the sale of B.  Then part or all of the deduction of the $500 loss could be delayed until the following tax  year, leaving you with taxes to pay on part or all of the $500 gain

Comment: This is all correct.  One thing I would add is that you still must report both the loss and the gain on your taxes (Schedule D in USA), otherwise IRS will flag it... one year I failed to report a buy and a sell of the same stock at *exact* same price.

Comment: All closed trades must be reported unless you are professional with Trader Tax Status which is then MTM accounting.